# Overriding Magento_SalesRule ResourceModel by preferences throws error: Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

Error Message in debug.log:

> [2020-11-10 07:57:17] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule, Argument 3 passed to Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon, instance of RM\SameCouponMultipleDiscounts\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon given, called in /home/rehan/lab/testrm/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []

I am trying to override: Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon.php to remove 'unique coupon' restriction:

```
$this->addUniqueField(['field' => 'code', 'title' => __('Coupon with the same code')]);
```

from construct() method.

My app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Coupon.php looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

/**
 * SalesRule Resource Coupon
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Coupon extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb implements
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Spi\CouponResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Constructor adds unique fields
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('salesrule_coupon', 'coupon_id');
    }
}
```

my di.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon" />
</config>
```

I've tried clearing cache, generated folder and did setup:di:compile but I am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your overridden class extends the original class so the other native classes that dependency injection original class can recognize your overridden one.

Alter

```
class Coupon extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb implements
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Spi\CouponResourceInterface
```

into

```
class Coupon extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon
```

But using preferences aren't recommended, you can try to find a better way.

Comment: Thanks James, that was indeed the fix to extend the original class. May I know why it isn't recommended to use preferences?

Comment: Using preferences makes the class is hard to upgradable and maintainable. If you upgrade the native Magento version, it could be conflicted. If you install other extensions that will have to intercept into this class, it will conflict too.